# Imported 3D Models are always white?

Tags: pcb, altium

Every time I try to create a footprint and embed an .stl file of the actual mechanical CAD of the part, the color information seems to get lost.

When I select the footprint in the .PcbLib file, under `Display >> 3D Color` I do see the color that I want but the model still shows up glaring white.

I can move on, but this seems to be an issue for a while now and at some point it'd be nice to fix, especially as I ship off screenshots of the model.

I'm attaching an example of a voltage regulator.

[image]

I'm using Altium 2010 I believe.

Comment: I never got the "3D Color" to do anything either; I'd like to know what the heck its for.

Comment: Can you export the 3d model from your mechanical CAD package as a step file (the AP 214 version), and import that into Altium?

Comment: AP214 version .step file solved the problem!!!  Thank you @gbmhunter.  I'll have to be more careful about what I grab from grabcad now I guess.  If you post your comment as a question I can mark it as the answer to close this thread

Comment: @tarabyte Have done, glad to of helped :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you export the 3d model from your mechanical CAD package as a step file (the AP 214 version), and import that into Altium?

These seem to retain colour information when importing into Altium.